# Creating a grid of data with php/mysql - union queries?

Tags: php, mysql, union

I'm attempting to create a grid of availability from a number of tables to present information as follows:

```
------------------------------------------------------
venue      |  22/11 |  23/11 | 24/11 | 25/11 | 26/11 |
------------------------------------------------------
Some venue |   £24  |   £25  |  £32  |  N/A  |  £65  |
------------------------------------------------------
Some venue |   £20  |   N/A  |  £22  |  £34  |  £43  |
-------------------------------------------------------
```

For each venue I can create a recordset for the selected date period using a query such as:

```
SELECT temp_date.queryDate, availability.venueId
FROM temp_date
LEFT JOIN availability
ON temp_date.queryDate = availability.date
AND availability.venueId = 7
GROUP BY temp_date.queryDate
ORDER BY temp_date.queryDate;
```

The key here being that I can return a null value for any dates that are unavailable whilst keeping my recordset to the correct number of days (ie. 5 entries for a working week).

To add each of the other venues to this list I was considering simply using a UNION query to combine the datasets into one like so:

```
(SELECT temp_date.queryDate, availability.venueId
FROM temp_date
LEFT JOIN availability
ON temp_date.queryDate = availability.date
AND availability.venueId = 7
GROUP BY temp_date.queryDate
ORDER BY temp_date.queryDate)
UNION
(SELECT temp_date.queryDate, availability.venueId
FROM temp_date
LEFT JOIN availability
ON temp_date.queryDate = availability.date
AND availability.venueId = 8
GROUP BY temp_date.queryDate
ORDER BY temp_date.queryDate);
```

My concern with this is with say 10 different venues that could be queried then the query could take quite a long time to run through.

So my question is as follows:  Is a UNION query my only option here or is there some alternative JOIN I can use to ensure that I get a full weeks results for all the venues being queried.

Hopefully this is clear :-S

**EDIT:**

To indicate what I'm after below are screenshots of the recordset required and current query:

[image]

[image]

Using IN() as suggested:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT  td.query_date, a.venueId
FROM    temp_date td
CROSS JOIN
        (
        SELECT  7 AS id
        UNION ALL
        SELECT  8 AS id
        ) ids
LEFT JOIN
        availability a
ON      a.date = td.query_date
        AND a.id = ids.id
ORDER BY
        ids.id, td.query_date
```

Also note that `GROUP BY` is not a correct method to handle duplicates here: in fact, your query would wail in any other system except `MySQL`, and even in `MySQL` with `ANSI` `GROUP BY` behavior enabled.

Are duplicates on `(date, id)` possible in `availability`? If yes, which of these duplicates should be selected?

Comment: thanks for this I will have a play shortly.  And no, (date, id) duplicates aren't possible on availability.

Comment: @simnom: you can get rid of `GROUP BY` then, it's redundant.

Comment: YOu should have a table of venues too, which would make the cross join simpler.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use IN() ?

```
SELECT temp_date.queryDate, availability.venueId
FROM temp_date
LEFT JOIN availability
ON temp_date.queryDate = availability.date
AND availability.venueId IN(7, 8)
GROUP BY temp_date.queryDate
ORDER BY temp_date.queryDate
```

Comment: Hi, been down this road, using IN() will just return me say 5 rows whereas I want 10 rows one "week" for each venue.

Comment: I've amended the original question to indicate what I mean in more detail.

Answer (score 0):

yes,definitely, as Webnet describe you can use IN statement for selecting your venueID.

```
SELECT temp_date.queryDate, availability.venueId

FROM temp_date
LEFT JOIN availability
ON temp_date.queryDate = availability.date
AND availability.venueId IN(7, 8)
GROUP BY temp_date.queryDate
ORDER BY temp_date.queryDate
```

Comment: As comment on @webnet's answer this doesn't give the desired result with only one entry for each entry in temp_date.  What I require is a venue/date entry for each venue/date combination.  i.e 5 entries for one venue/week, 10 entries for two venues/week.

Comment: I've amended the original question to indicate what I mean in more detail.